# Bot Framework- Skype for business - Is file upload attachment is possible? I know Button/Cards/Forms not supported by this channel

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business

Bot Framework- Skype for business - Is upload attachment to the bot is possible? I know Button/Cards/Forms not supported by this channel. Is uploading an attachment also not supported?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading an attachment in Skype for business is also not supported, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/overview#feature-support for all the features supported currently. Also, Skype for Business channel is being deprecated on the Bot Framework.